# How to set Principal in Kafka console producer/consumer?

Tags: authentication, authorization, apache-kafka, kerberos, producer-consumer

I want to experiment with ACL's in Kafka. So I have created some ACL's for a sample topic **test** in my Zookeeper which allows producer permission to ***User:Bob*** principal and consumer permission to ***User:Alice*** principal.

Now when I am using the kafka-console-producer or the consumer how do I mention the **principal** for this producer or consumer?

I tried setting a new config like **principal=User:Bob** inside the *producer/consumer.properties* file but it says it's an unrecognized config.

Can someone help me figure this out? 
Or Have I understood the idea of Principal wrong? Is it something to do with Kerberos based authentication?

Thanks in advance,
Shabir

Comment: I think **Principal** in this context means the Principal of the certificate attached to the client who is communicating with the broker. If it is not please clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was experimenting with the above scenario by means of following a blog and figured out that **Principal** here actually means the **CN (Common Name)** attribute of an SSL communication.

Kafka uses the **CN** of the communicating server's SSL certificate to identify the *user* and to do authentication and authorization accordingly.

Thus, there is no place to explicitly mention the **principal** when running the *consumer* or the *producer*. It is taken from the SSL certificate's CN attribute.

Thanks
Shabir

Comment: Explicitly mentioning the principal may not make much sense as one can set any principal you want.